# Optaplanner domain model moves: can you "twiddle" items in a set as a move?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm new to Optaplanner, and have been trying to look through the documentation to optimally encode moves for my problem.

I have a set of items I that are partitioned into subsets S1, S2, ... S_n.  I want to choose items so that I get the maximum global score.

Each element of the partition S_k has a maximum cardinality (capacity) of items that it can choose.  When chosen, the items interact in ways that make the global score NP complete, but adding items to a partition always is a non-decreasing operation for the global score, so I want to maintain that each set S_k has max capacity.

What I have now is that Items are a `@PlanningEntity` containing a boolean `@PlanningVariable` as to whether the item is selected in the global solution.  This leads to Optaplanner adding and removing items globally across all partition sets, but this is very inefficient.  During search, it removes an element from one set S_l and adds an element to a different partition S_m, which leads to one set being under capacity and (sometimes) another being over capacity.  What I want to be able to do is have a move "twiddle" a subset by swapping one item in the subset with another, so that the sets are always at capacity.

Is there any way to do this with Optaplanner?  I could not see how to do it, but I have only been playing with it for a few days.

Thank you very much in advance!